# html to pdf in ios shows extra spacing

Tags: html, ios, pdf

I am converting html to pdf using NDHTMLtoPDF in ios. My problem is some time at bottom of pdf page random space is included or some time design is overlap.
my html is look exactly same how i want.

Comment: I know that this was a long time ago, but did you get a solution for this problem? I'm using also NDHTMLtoPDF and I'm getting the same result.